# How to prevent the inner ListBox's scrolling in nested ListBoxes? (WP8)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have nested ListBoxes:

```
<ListBox Name="listbox" Padding="0,0,0,100" Loaded="listbox_Loaded" Foreground="Black">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" Foreground="Black">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When I touch and drag items from inner listbox it plays scroll animation for this inner listbox. How to prevent this behavior? I need to scroll the outer listbox only, but the items from inner listbox still must be selectable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change `Template` of inner `ListBox` to be only `ItemsPresenter`. This will remove `ScrollViewer` which is normally part of that template:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" Foreground="Black">
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
            <ItemsPresenter/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```